# Generic Active Probes

Tags: oscilloscope, test, spectrum-analyzer

I need an active probe for use with a spectrum analyzer and oscilloscope. My scope has contacts around the BNC connector for powering a compatible probe. The spectrum analyzer is a different story. There is no port for powering a probe.

Looking around I see that the [Tek 6201](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Tektronix-P6201-Oscilloscope-Fet-Probe-DC-to-900MHz-50ohm-Term-010-6201-00-/200824442765?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2ec211cf8d) seems fairly generic with a lead to be attached to power. Something generic is preferable as I want to use this with both of my instruments. Would this suffice? If so, how do I power it? Specifically, what voltage/current requirements and interface?

My scope is a Tek MSO2024 and my spectrum analyzer is a Rigol DSA815.

Comment: What are the model numbers for your Scope and SA?

Comment: @OliGlaser Added the information to the question... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference....

I found that Tek makes power supplies for their probes so that an active probe can be used on test equipment that is not compatible. In my case, I opted to purchase a P6201 active probe along with a 1101 power supply (both Tektronix parts).

Answer (score 0):

While not useful for all situations, I tend not to use active probes any more and instead use a resitive probe, which I learned about from [Howard Johnston](http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/news/5_4.htm).  For all but very low level signals it works very well.

This will partially solve your issue.